# Heaviside and trig function integral $\int \sin(3t)\theta(t)dt $

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, step-function

I can't figure out how you're supposed to find the solutions for a product involving trigonometric functions with heaviside, most examples online involve exponentials which have the nice property of being their own derivative/integral.

$$\int \sin(3t)\theta(t)dt $$

Wolfram gives me the following answer.

[image]

I know you can split up definite integrals piecewise where heaviside evaluates to 0 and 1 respectively, but how would you go about solving indefinite integrals in this way, especially trigonometric ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate by parts,

$$\begin{align}
&\int \sin3t\theta(t)dt =-\frac13\int d(\cos3t)\theta(t)dt \\
=&-\frac13\theta(t)\cos3t+\frac13\int \cos3t\delta(t)dt\\
=&-\frac13\theta(t)\cos3t+\frac13\theta(t)\cos(0)\\
=&\frac13\theta(t)(1-\cos3t)=\frac23\theta(t)\sin^2\frac{3t}2
\end{align}$$

where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta function, the derivative of the Heaviside function $\theta(t)$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but what trig rules do you use to rewrite the expression to use sin in the last step?

Comment: @DeadPixel - the half angle identity $\cos x=1-2\sin^2\frac x2$